# Is there a lablled dataset for rate-of-speech? With labels like fast,medium,slow or based on words-per-minute?

Tags: audio, dataset, speech-recognition

I am doing a project on ML for finding the rate-of-speech from an audio file.
I couldn't find a labeled dataset for it.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can time-align dataset like TEDLIUM with word timestamps and calculate the rate of speech from it.

If you need variety of rates, it is probably better to dump youtube audios and use recognized word timestamps since most datasets are pretty uniform in terms of rate.